# Details of C++ Vector push_back()

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to debug a program, and in doing so have bumped up against my understanding of the C++ vector push_back() function.

To illustrate my point, I've written the following short program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;

class Test {
private:
  int mTestMember;
public:
  Test(int val);
  Test(const Test&);

  int GetValue() const;
};

Test::Test(int val)
{
  cout << "Constructor\n";
  mTestMember = val;
}

Test::Test(const Test& test)
{
  cout << "Copy Constructor\n";
  mTestMember = test.mTestMember;
  cout << "mTestMember: " << mTestMember << endl;
}

int main(){

  vector<Test> tests;
  tests.push_back(Test(int(5)));
  cout<< endl;
  tests.push_back(Test(int(6)));
  cout << endl;
  tests.push_back(Test(int(7)));

  return(0);
}
```

and if I compile and run, I get the following output:

```
Constructor
Copy Constructor
mTestMember: 5

Constructor
Copy Constructor
mTestMember: 6
Copy Constructor
mTestMember: 5

Constructor
Copy Constructor
mTestMember: 7
Copy Constructor
mTestMember: 5
Copy Constructor
mTestMember: 6
```

It would appear that, in the process of the push_back() function, a copy is performed of the object that is passed as the argument to the push_back() function (which I already knew), and then the rest of the elements that were present in the pre-existing are also copied to the new vector starting from the front.

Am I correct in my understanding of the process?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`std::vector` stores its elements in an array.  An array always has fixed size, so if you keep adding elements to a `std::vector`, its underlying array will eventually fill up.  When the array is full and you add another element (via `push_back` or another member function that adds new elements), it must:

1. Create a new, larger array,
2. Copy or move<sup>(*)</sup> the elements from the old array to the new array,
3. Insert the new element into the new array, and
4. Destroy the old array

This process is called *reallocation*.  A correct implementation of `std::vector` should resize the array exponentially.  The Visual C++ `std::vector` implementation uses a growth factor of 1.5x; other implementations may use a different growth factor.

---

<sup>(*) C++11 adds support for *moving* objects.</sup>

Comment: Apparently his implementation of `vector` resizes the array up by 1 on each reallocation?

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Not allowed (though with tiny arrays it might look that way). It *must* resize by a factor, not simply add a constant amount of more size. Otherwise the `amortized constant` requirement won't be met.

Comment: Is the behaviour in which the copy constructor for the new element is called before those of the rest of the elements standard, or is it dependent on the implementation? (I'm compiling with g++ 4.4.3).

Comment: But if you only have a few items and a relatively low factor, it might work out to be +1 for the first few push_backs.

Comment: @Wheels2050:  I think the ordering of steps (2) and (3) is implementation-defined.  I do not have the specification handy, though.  (However, I would operate under the assumption that either could happen first:  it should not matter to your code.)

Comment: @James: Thanks very much for your detailed answers. You're right in that it doesn't matter as far as my code is concerned, but I was just thrown when what I was printing out wasn't what I was expecting (due to the order in which the copy constructors were called) and I thought at first that something funny was going on.

Comment: The MSVC growth factor is actually 1.5x. Buried in the implementation you can see that it does `capacity() + capacity()/2`.

Comment: @JerryCoffin:  Yes, of course.  Added.  [Aside:  The C++ object model was already rather complex; adding move semantics has made it far more so.  Move semantics make answering questions like this one more difficult:  one the one hand, one wants to provide a simple answer that describes the observed behavior.  On the other hand, one wants to provide a complete, fully correct answer, so as not to unintentionally mislead.  I don't know about anyone else here, but I am certain I have yet to figure out where the right balance is.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: Yeah -- it was never easy, and it's just getting harder. I'm at least equally uncertain about the right balance as well.